# A couple of issues with installing Unreal Engine under Linux

Tags: linux, unreal-engine4, game-development

I'm absolutely new to this, but I decided to try myself in game development with Unreal Engine. It's complicated by the fact that I have Linux and had to compile everything from the source code myself. So, at the moment I have two problems that I have no idea about.

1) The folder with my Unreal Engine weighs as much as 75 gigabytes. Is that okay? If not, then how can I reduce it? (since I didn't have enough space on my laptop to install, I had to do a perversion - compile the source code that was on my external hard drive, and the program additionally tightened all the dependencies)

2) When I run the IDE, the entire interface is on the wrong scale ([in the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ST137.jpg)). How can I fix it?

Again, I'm totally new at all this, and I don't even know which way to dig to get the information I need.

Comment: 1). Yes, that's fine. You can delete starter content and plugins with content if you want to claw back a few gigs. Probably not worth it though. 2). Window -> Reset Editor Layout might work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a very good answer since I have yet to try out the steps myself. It's meant to provide a direction toward an answer, but it's too long for a comment. Please edit this answer or answer separately if you have confirmed it or have a better one.

From the documentation ( https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Platforms/Linux/BeginnerLinuxDeveloper/SettingUpAnUnrealWorkflow/index.html ), note that you can reduce the size of the downloaded source by downloading the ZIP instead of cloning the repo.

In addition, once you have compiled the binary and ensured that it's working, I think you can safely delete all the files outside the `Engine/Binaries` directory.

With respect to scaling, you should be able to scale the UI down by Window > Developer Tools > Widget Reflector. (from https://forums.unrealengine.com/unreal-engine/feedback-for-epic/9533-high-resolution-display-support-for-editor)

Answer (score 0):

just sharing some more info i found in case it helps the next person. I also ran into the same UI scaling on Ubuntu 20.04, and I was able to fix it by  opening a project and navigating to `Edit->Editor Preferences...` and the unchecking the box next to `Enable High DPI Support`.

I'm pretty new to UE4 in general, not sure if this is the 'correct' way to fix this or not, but it worked for me and I haven't had any issues since.

Unrelated but a noteworthy UE4 Linux issue - if you're looking to add marketplace assets to your project while on a Linux machine epic has done you no favors. You'll either have to mess with Lutris / Wine to emulate the Epic Games launcher and then symlink your projects into the Wine Windows FS so the launcher can find them *or you could alternatively* use the  [nmrugg/UE4Launcher](https://github.com/nmrugg/UE4Launcher) project to manage marketplace assets.